# raspbian: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google_auth_oauthlib'

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspbian, distutils

I am trying to install a Python script which does a:

```
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
```

however the returned error on execution is:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google/google_calendar_service.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google/google_calendar_service.py", line 3, in <module>
    from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google_auth_oauthlib'
```

I tried inserting "google-auth-oauthlib" as requirement in the distutils setup.py, with or without version, tried also the name of the package "python3-google-auth-oauthlib" but nothing works:

```
install_requires=['google-api-python-client>=2.3.0',
                  'google-auth-oauthlib>=0.4.1',
                  'google-auth>=1.30.0',
                  'python3-google-auth-oauthlib'],
```

in the end I tried manually installing it:

```
sudo pip install google-auth-oauthlib
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting google-auth-oauthlib
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7b/b8/88def36e74bee9fce511c9519571f4e485e890093ab7442284f4ffaef60b/google_auth_oauthlib-0.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting google-auth (from google-auth-oauthlib)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d2/c1/44179a1cfc5c3b5832a5f9c925161612471ec5f346bcd186235651d74f35/google_auth-1.30.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (146kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 153kB 46kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from google-auth->google-auth-oauthlib) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=40.3.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from google-auth->google-auth-oauthlib) (40.8.0)
Collecting pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 (from google-auth->google-auth-oauthlib)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/95/de/214830a981892a3e286c3794f41ae67a4495df1108c3da8a9f62159b9a9d/pyasn1_modules-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (155kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 43kB/s 
Collecting rsa<4.6; python_version < "3.6" (from google-auth->google-auth-oauthlib)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/26/f8/8127fdda0294f044121d20aac7785feb810e159098447967a6103dedfb96/rsa-4.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0 (from google-auth->google-auth-oauthlib)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2f/a6/30b0a0bef12283e83e58c1d6e7b5aabc7acfc4110df81a4471655d33e704/cachetools-3.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6 (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth->google-auth-oauthlib)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/1e/a94a8d635fa3ce4cfc7f506003548d0a2447ae76fd5ca53932970fe3053f/pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 66kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pyasn1, pyasn1-modules, rsa, cachetools, google-auth, google-auth-oauthlib
Successfully installed cachetools-3.1.1 google-auth-1.30.0 google-auth-oauthlib-0.4.1 pyasn1-0.4.8 pyasn1-modules-0.2.8 rsa-4.5
```

still the same error.

Comment: `pip` → Python 2; `pip3` → Python 3

Comment: have you tried `usr/bin/python3 -m pip install google-auth-oauthlib`

Comment: thank you that solved it, still wondering why distutils "install_requires" doesn't solve this automatically. issuing this manually before installing the deb is cumbersome.